# OpenGL ES 2.0: Vertex and Fragment Shader for 2D with Transparency

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, graphics-programming

Could I knindly ask for correct examples of **OpenGL ES 2.0 Vertex and Fragment shader** for displaying 2D textured sprites **with transparency**?

I have fairly simple shaders that display textured polygon pairs but transparency is not applied despite:

- texture map contains transparency information
- Blending is enabled: glEnable(GL_BLEND); glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

*My Vertex Shader:*

```
uniform mat4 uOrthoProjection;
uniform vec3 Translation;

attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec2 TextureCoord;

varying vec2 TextureCoordOut;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = uOrthoProjection * (Position + vec4(Translation, 0));
    TextureCoordOut = TextureCoord;
}
```

*My Fragment Shader:*

```
varying mediump vec2 TextureCoordOut;
uniform sampler2D Sampler;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bunkai (I expect that Bunkai is your first name),

turn off the depthBufer. Do you use depth (different Z)? If not why depthBuffer? It is for 3D or layered 2D.

Transparent objects are rendered **always** after opaque objects. Do you use this order?

It must be one of this, i'm sure.

Comment: @Notabene: +1 for trying to thelp. Hi, well, I have multiple layers, and further layers are supposed to move slower (paralax scrolling) so z-buffer is used to solve transparency issues. However, I have more information: **It is the polygons, that are not transparent, not the textures.** I set glClearColor() to red, to see what happens. Actually, the texture itself becomes transparent, as the transparent areas of the texture become red. However, for some reason, the polygon keeps displaying glClearColor, instead of becoming transparent. Any idea why?

Comment: Transparent objects must be rendered after opaque objects... It is not sure that this rule has been followed.

Comment: if alpha is null, you see the glClearColor. Full transparent is invisible...

Comment: @Notabene: to be sure all your questions are answerred, in this phase, I use only one layer, but as the objects are set one next to the other, I noticed that the areas that are supposed to be transparent hide neighbour sprites and overdraw them with black (the color set in `glClearColor()`)

Comment: You draw order is not corred. You draw the transparent surface and after the neighbour sprites. Do you have sorted your transparent surfaces ?

Comment: @Ellis: yes, that is my case.. I see glClearColor in areas that are supposed to be transparent. However, I do not see any pattern in wrong organizing. Every object I draw has some areas transparent. Whichever object I draw as the last will obscure the object below, by overwriting areas that should be normally seen.

Comment: @Ellis It is sure. Read your alpha blending. Opaque object (alpha = 1) if rendered after, will overwrite transparent object. It is common for game engines. Depth prepass, generate shadow maps, opaque objects, then stuff like mirrors and last transparent objects (they have to be ordered or depth peeling have to be used).

Comment: @Ellis, I have not sorted transparent surfaces, as they all have some areas transparent. There are spheres and different irregular objects, and every object has some portions to be cut out, as they all are placed on rectangular polygons.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori And what exactly do you mean when you say polygon pairs?

Comment: @Notabene: imagine, you have 2D sprites while every sprite has some portions that must be transparent, as no sprite is perfectly rectangular. Does in this case transparency sorting play any important role? How to sort the objects if every of them has some areas transparent?

Comment: @Notabene: In OpenGL ES, there are no quad polygons. Sprites have to be of course rectangular, so in OpenGL ES, to construct a rectangular polyogn, I have to construct it from two triangles. Therefore, one quad polygon sprite == polygon pair consisting of two triangular polygons.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori Yes unfortunately you have to sort them. Imagine it like photoshop layers. If you say that you have layers i suggest do one render pass of every layer. Starting from back to the camera.

Comment: @Notabene, @Ellis: Despite I did not believe it, I have placed one object closer to me (in the Z-Buffer) to be rendered later, and suprisingly, it became rendered correctly. Thanks to you guys. Now, i will have to figure out, how to sort objects so, that they get rendered correctly, if they all have some areas transparent.

Comment: @Notabene: how would you transparency-sort objects in one layer, if they are posisitioned next to each other, but still some of their parts overlap, and areas that are supposed to be transparent hide neigbour sprites, and overwrite them by glClearColor?

Comment: I have disabled GL_DEPTH_TEST, and all my issues with overwritting disapeared. That is great. now I understand, that all my objects are drawn at the same layer, but maybe now, with correct ordering, I will be able to achieve layered and paralax scrolling effects.

Comment: Both, Notabene and Ellis proposed the simmilar solution - to perform transparency sorting. Thank you. However, because this answer clearly identified my problem in it's body, I am marking it as the *Accepted Answer*

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori You can easily specify order in vbo. It is just order of vertices (or indices). But if you are dooing parallax scrolling, why not to use layers? Even picture on wikipedia says so: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_scrolling . And one last thing to thing about. You can specify depth of layer (Z) and use perspective projection instead of ortho. Then you only change camera position and scrollng paralax works for free. No need of different offsets for layers...

Comment: @Notabene: that is great idea with using perspective projection instead of ortho view. Although I haven't tried it, I have read, that with perspective projection there is loss of tiny details on the objects for objects too far or too close (resulting from resizing objects). Of course, I can not test everything what I read, but it sounds logical. What is your opinion?

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori I'm sure (as a 3D programmer) that it is not truth. Well known problem with perspective projection is the depth buffer precision between the near and far. But you cannot experience any problems with few layer.

Comment: @Notabene: As you ahve 3D programminge experience, is there really **no texture bluring** caused with rendering the textured polygon with persepective projection vs ortho view?

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori This is long discussion :). No. I'm 99.9% sure that it is not truth. Texture bluring can be caused only if polygons size on the screen is bigger than texture resolution. It can be with glOrtho as well. You should maybe little study more what happens between vertex shader and pixel shader (no offense in this ;-)). Projection matrix plays with vertices on vertex shader. Than rasterisation takes place and it works same for ortho and projection(because it works over transformed vertices). And then there is pixel shader working with textures. So i think it is the same.

Comment: @Notabene: thank you for your precious advices. Yes, I read OpenGL Superbible and another resources continuously. Things gradually start making sense, as I learn things all around. But I need to understand more topics, so all fits together as a puzzle.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that your texture has an alpha channel. Add this line in your fragment shader:

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(Sampler, TextureCoordOut).xyz, 0.5);
```

You should see some half transparency texture.

Ps: Your result color will be darker, because it is a mix with color in backbuffer*0.5 and the gl_FragColor*0.5. Blending is done after the fragment in the OGLES 2.0 pipeline.

Your equation is:

```
ResultColor.r = glFragColor.r * glFragColor.a + ColorInBuffer.r * (1.-glFragColor.a)
ResultColor.g = glFragColor.g * glFragColor.a + ColorInBuffer.g * (1.-glFragColor.a)
ResultColor.b = glFragColor.b * glFragColor.a + ColorInBuffer.b * (1.-glFragColor.a)
```

Comment: +1 for relevant response. Hi, Ellis, thanks for responding. I load .png texture file into OpenGL. Before loading that file, I opened it in Photoshop, and yes, alpha layer was present. I tried to add your line into fragment shader. The result was that all the objects in the scene were 50% darker, but where they overlapped, they were not transparent at all. What conclusion comes from this experiment?

Comment: hmm, is it possible, that I have issues with blending seetings instead of presence of transparency information in the texture map?

Answer (score 0):

enable blending
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
also,check if texture has alpha channel
opaque, rendered front to back
transparent, back to front